# How to return array as an output after the execution of forEach loop?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array in which project _id is stored in the **user** collection. I'm initially fetching that array and then I'm trying to retrieve the data corresponding to the _id (stored in user collection) stored if **projects** collection. The data retrieved is pushed on to the array and that array is returned as an output.
But I'm unable to do so. An empty array is being returned.

```
var projectInfo= new Array();

users.post('/retrieveProjects', function(user, res, next) { 
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("EMWorks");
    dbo.collection("users").findOne({_id:user.body.userid})
    .then(response => {
      if(response)
      {
        console.log(response);
        (response.project).forEach(element => {
          dbo.collection("projects").findOne({_id:element})
          .then(respo => {
            console.log(respo);
            projectInfo.push(respo);
          });
          console.log(projectInfo) ;
        });

      }else{
        console.log("No Projects created yet...!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHAI9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `dbo.collection("projects").findOne` is async and returns a promise.
The forEach loop runs and generates these promises for each elemnt, but does not wait for its execution.
The promises are not resolved when the loop finishes and an empty array is returned.
You can wait for the promises to be executed and return the array only after that:

```
const promises = [];
(response.project).forEach(element => {
      promises.push(dbo.collection("projects").findOne({_id:element})
      .then(respo => {
        console.log(respo);
        projectInfo.push(respo);
      });
    }));
   Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
      console.log(projectInfo) ;
 });
```

This can also be simplified with the map function and async/await :

```
const promises = (response.project).map(async element => {
      const respo  = await dbo.collection("projects").findOne({_id:element});
      projectInfo.push(respo);
    });
   Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
      console.log(projectInfo) ;
 });
```